# How to print as string a parameter which is a list from class in python

Tags: python, list, class, printing

I want to print all grades as a csv string for the particular Student. How can i achieve this as it prints out memory location instead:

```
class Student:
  def __init__(self,name,year):
    self.name = name
    self.year = year
    self.grades = []
    def add_grade(self,grade):
      if type(grade) == Grade:
        self.grades.append(grade)
      else:
        pass
    def __repr__(self):
      return "Student name is {name} and attends year {year}".format(name=self.name, year=self.year)

pieter = Student("Pieter Bruegel the Elder",8)

class Grade:
  minimum_passing = 65
  def __init__(self,score):
    self.score = score


pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(95))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(85))
print(str(pieter.grades)) #this one prints [<__main__.Grade object at 0x7fc3874d76d8>]
print(pieter)
```

I also added it in the __repr__ but still the same.

Comment: Did you really intend to nest the `add_grade` and `__repr__` methods inside `__init__`? Correct indentation is crucial in Python.

Comment: You have `__repr__` for `Student`, but you're printing a `Grade` object.

Comment: There appears to be little reason to define a `Grade` class instead of just using `int`.

Comment: @chepner Based on the `minimum_passing` variable, it looks like there's going to be more code in the class that implements some logic, like returning all passing grades.

Comment: @Barmar You could still write a simple function like `passing_grades = lambda grades, minimum=65: filter(lambda x: x < minimum, grades)` (using lambda expressions here just to fit in the comment). (Clearly I'm in the "use classes sparingly" camp, but printing an `int` doesn't require any extra work.)

Comment: @chepner I'm thinking of something like `g = Grade(85); if g.isPassing(): ...`

Comment: You should have `__repr__` for `Grade`. Then look at `print(Grade(100))`

Answer (score 1):

Give `Grade` a `__str__` method that returns the score as a string.

```
class Grade:
  minimum_passing = 65
  def __init__(self,score):
    self.score = score
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.score)
```

Then `print(pieter.grades)` should print:

```
[100,95,85]
```

You can't get rid of the `[]` surrounding it, because that's the way lists print. You can't customize the container's printing from the elements within it. If you need to do that, you should define your own `GradeList` class.